# Is there a solution to uploading csv file to SQL

Tags: sql, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Anytime I tried uploading CSV file to Google Cloud Bigquery, I kept getting an error response. I tried Google drive to upload but it won't show the preview button on the table. I need help on how I can resolve this please.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? How are you uploading the file? How big is the file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Loading CSV data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table). I used the following python code and I was able to load csv file to Bigquery successfully:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]